# convert a common pdf to multiple images but encounter security error

Tags: pdf, imagemagick

I tried to convert a downloaded pdf to multiple pages with commands

```
$ convert -density 300 magit.pdf -quality 100 magit-%04d.jpg
```

thus get error

```
convert-im6.q16: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `PDF' @ error/constitute.c/IsCoderAuthorized/408.
convert-im6.q16: no images defined `magit-%04d.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.
```

Checked the imageMagich manual and some answers, but found no problems with my usage.

My machine:

```
OS: Ubuntu 19.10 x86_64 
Host: MacBookPro11,1 1.0 
Kernel: 5.3.0-22-generic 
Uptime: 6 hours, 33 mins 
Packages: 2554 (dpkg), 2 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.0.3 
Resolution: 2560x1600 
DE: KDE 
WM: KWin 
Theme: Breeze [KDE], Breeze [GTK3] 
Icons: breeze [KDE], breeze [GTK3] 
Terminal: konsole 
Terminal Font: Noto Sans [GOOG] 9 
CPU: Intel i5-4258U (4) @ 2.900GHz 
GPU: Intel Haswell-ULT 
Memory: 2935MiB / 3844MiB
```